# xsd.exe converts unsignedShort to byte

Tags: c#, xsd

I'm using xsd.exe to generate a class for a schema.
The schema defines one attribute as xs:unsignedShort.

```
<xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:unsignedShort"  use="required"/>
```

In the generated class this gets defined as one single byte.

```
private byte numberField;
```

I would need to parse a number from a string and assign this field with that value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. If I run xsd against a schema containing the above attribute declaration, it produces a `ushort` property/field. There again, it's unclear what the rest of the question is about either.

Comment: I'll try to edit my post to include a schema reproducing my issue.

Comment: You're right. In a simple scenario I couldn't reproduce the issue. I had some other attributes declared as unsignedByte. When I changed thoose to unsignedShort my problem disappeared.